# how to fix my if condition when to validate the day and month

Tags: python

```
def user_input_validation(user_input_month , user_input_day):
 if user_input_month < 1 or user_input_month > 12 :
  valid_month = False
  print ("Invalid month. Please enter a number between 1-12")
 else :
  valid_month = True
 if user_input_day  < 1 or user_input_day > 31 : 
  valid_day = False
  print ("Invalid day. Please enter a number between 1-12")
 else :
  valid_day = True 
 if valid_month=True and valid_day = True :
   return True
```

my error massage
File "", line 13
if valid_month = True and valid_day = True :
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: `=` is for assignment, `==` test for equality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in if statement we should use double ==
the right syntax is

if valid_month==True and valid_day ==True :

Answer (score 0):

Generally `=` is for assignment, and `==` tests for equality. That being said, you can simplify your logic (and increase your indentation):

```
def user_input_validation(user_input_month, user_input_day):
    valid_month = 1 <= user_input_month <= 12
    valid_day = 1 <= user_input_day <= 31
    if not valid_month:
        print("Invalid month. Please enter a number between 1-12") 
    if not valid_day:
        print("Invalid day. Please enter a number between 1-31")
    return valid_month and valid_day
```

Answer (score 0):

This is Correct: Replace '=' with '=='. Because you're checking not assigning.

```
def user_input_validation(user_input_month , user_input_day):
     if (user_input_month < 1 or user_input_month > 12 :
      valid_month = False
      print ("Invalid month. Please enter a number between 1-12")
     else :
      valid_month = True
     if user_input_day  < 1 or user_input_day > 31 : 
      valid_day = False
      print ("Invalid day. Please enter a number between 1-12")
     else :
      valid_day = True 
     if valid_month==True and valid_day == True :
       return True
```